# parsing .properties file in Python

Tags: python, key-value, ini

The [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser) module raises an exception if one parses a simple Java-style **`.properties`**  file, whose content is key-value pairs (i..e without INI-style section headers). Is there some workaround?

Comment: It seems to me the Properties format (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) is somewhat more expressive than ConfigParser style ini files. Hence it's probably not a good idea to try and shoehorn it. Instead try jython or this snippet: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496795-a-python-replacement-for-javautilproperties/

Answer (score 80):

Say you have, e.g.:

```
$ cat my.props
first: primo
second: secondo
third: terzo
```

i.e. would be a `.config` format except that it's missing a leading section name.  Then, it easy to fake the section header:

```
import ConfigParser

class FakeSecHead(object):
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp
        self.sechead = '[asection]\n'

    def readline(self):
        if self.sechead:
            try: 
                return self.sechead
            finally: 
                self.sechead = None
        else: 
            return self.fp.readline()
```

**usage:**

```
cp = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
cp.readfp(FakeSecHead(open('my.props')))
print cp.items('asection')
```

**output:**

```
[('second', 'secondo'), ('third', 'terzo'), ('first', 'primo')]
```

Comment: would be great if there was an option in `configparser` to suppress that exception, for the sake of mere mortals like me :)

Comment: great solution, but it can be shortened a lot:
`def FakeSecHead(fp):
    yield '[asection]\n';
    yield from fp`

Comment: would that work for writing into the config file too?

Answer (score 80):

I thought [MestreLion's "read_string" comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819696/parsing-properties-file-in-python/25493615#comment26110228_8555776) was nice and simple and deserved an example.

For Python 3.2+, you can implement the "dummy section" idea like this:

```
with open(CONFIG_PATH, 'r') as f:
    config_string = '[dummy_section]\n' + f.read()
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_string(config_string)
```

Comment: Elegant. Except for the fact that you need to ensure that the CONFIG_PATH, a.k.a configuration file, exists. Which configparsers built-in does for you. But I guess that's just a try away ;-)

Answer (score 32):

My solution is to use `StringIO` and prepend a simple dummy header:

```
import StringIO
import os
config = StringIO.StringIO()
config.write('[dummysection]\n')
config.write(open('myrealconfig.ini').read())
config.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

import ConfigParser
cp = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
cp.readfp(config)
somevalue = cp.getint('dummysection', 'somevalue')
```

Comment: Added the needed `\n` and removed the unnecessary `'r'` mode on the `open()` call.

Comment: I find this the simplest solution.

Comment: I have newlines in my ini, how to work with that? Ie: one setting has it's several entries, one on it's own line.

Comment: This is a nice quick solution, but note that a Java properties file could use features that could break a ConfigParser, e.g., `!` as comment or \ (backslash) for line continuation and escapes (among others). More details of such features can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html.

Answer (score 23):

Alex Martelli's answer above does not work for Python 3.2+: `readfp()` has been replaced by `read_file()`, and it now takes an iterator instead of using the `readline()` method.

Here's a snippet that uses the same approach, but works in Python 3.2+.

```
>>> import configparser
>>> def add_section_header(properties_file, header_name):
...   # configparser.ConfigParser requires at least one section header in a properties file.
...   # Our properties file doesn't have one, so add a header to it on the fly.
...   yield '[{}]\n'.format(header_name)
...   for line in properties_file:
...     yield line
...
>>> file = open('my.props', encoding="utf_8")
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read_file(add_section_header(file, 'asection'), source='my.props')
>>> config['asection']['first']
'primo'
>>> dict(config['asection'])
{'second': 'secondo', 'third': 'terzo', 'first': 'primo'}
>>>
```

Comment: Python 3.2 also added `read_string()`, which makes appending the dummy section a trivial task.

Comment: The `add_section_header` can simply be: `config.read_file(itertools.chain(['[SECTION_NAME]'], file))`

Answer (score 10):

```
with open('some.properties') as file:
    props = dict(line.strip().split('=', 1) for line in file)
```

Credit to [How to create a dictionary that contains key‐value pairs from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574702/python-how-to-create-a-dictionary-that-contains-key-value-pairs-from-a-text-fil/32574836#32574836)

`maxsplit=1` is important if there are equal signs in the value (e.g. `someUrl=https://some.site.com/endpoint?id=some-value&someotherkey=value`)

Comment: This will error if the file has comments. We can avoid by using this: `dict(line.strip().split('=', 1) for line in file if not line.startswith("#") and not len(line.strip()) == 0)`

Answer (score 7):

#### YAY! another version

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8657601/3191896) (the addition is using a `dict`, `with` statement, and supporting the `%` character)

```
import ConfigParser
import StringIO
import os

def read_properties_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        config = StringIO.StringIO()
        config.write('[dummy_section]\n')
        config.write(f.read().replace('%', '%%'))
        config.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

        cp = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
        cp.readfp(config)

        return dict(cp.items('dummy_section'))
```

Usage

```
props = read_properties_file('/tmp/database.properties')

# It will raise if `name` is not in the properties file
name = props['name']

# And if you deal with optional settings, use:
connection_string = props.get('connection-string')
password = props.get('password')

print name, connection_string, password
```

---

the `.properties` file used in my example

```
name=mongo
connection-string=mongodb://...
password=my-password%1234
```

### Edit 2015-11-06

Thanks to [Neill Lima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643503/neill-lima) mentioning there was an issue with the `%` character.

The reason for that is `ConfigParser` designed to parse `.ini` files. The `%` character is a special syntax. in order to use the `%` character simply added a a replace for `%` with `%%` according to `.ini` syntax.

Comment: This solution worked well for me up to the point I had a password with '%' - no single quotes, and it crashed the ConfigParser. Python 2.7.6

Comment: your solution worked for me but I had to adapt for multiple lines with an additional `.replace('\\\n', ''))`
Basically any additional condition can go with the `write... replace`

Comment: `.replace('%', '%%')` gives incorrect results if there are multiple `%` in the source. It is better to use a dummy interpolation instead of `.replace('%', '%%')`: `configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.Interpolation())` which doesn't change `%` in any way. Python 3.9

Answer (score 4):

```
from pyjavaproperties import Properties
p = Properties()
p.load(open('test.properties'))
p.list()
print p
print p.items()
print p['name3']
p['name3'] = 'changed = value'
print p['name3']
p['new key'] = 'new value'
p.store(open('test2.properties','w'))
```

Comment: The only person to use an actual library made for Java properties files. I will use this and get back on its ease of use compared to others.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26859985/456550) suggests using itertools.chain in Python 3.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
from itertools import chain

parser = ConfigParser()
with open("foo.conf") as lines:
    lines = chain(("[dummysection]",), lines)  # This line does the trick.
    parser.read_file(lines)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('mykeyvaluepairs.properties') as f:
    defaults = dict([line.split() for line in f])
config = configparser.ConfigParser(defaults)
config.add_section('dummy_section')
```

Now `config.get('dummy_section', option)` will return 'option' from the DEFAULT section.

or:

```
with open('mykeyvaluepairs.properties') as f:
    properties = dict([line.split() for line in f])
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section('properties')
for prop, val in properties.items():
    config.set('properties', prop, val)
```

In which case `config.get('properties', option)` doesn't resort to the default section.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another answer for python2.7 based on [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819696/parsing-properties-file-in-python/2819788#2819788)

```
import ConfigParser

class PropertiesParser(object):

    """Parse a java like properties file

    Parser wrapping around ConfigParser allowing reading of java like
    properties file. Based on stackoverflow example:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819696/parsing-properties-file-in-python/2819788#2819788

    Example usage
    -------------
    >>> pp = PropertiesParser()
    >>> props = pp.parse('/home/kola/configfiles/dev/application.properties')
    >>> print props

    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.secheadname = 'fakeSectionHead'
        self.sechead = '[' + self.secheadname + ']\n'

    def readline(self):
        if self.sechead:
            try:
                return self.sechead
            finally:
                self.sechead = None
        else:
            return self.fp.readline()

    def parse(self, filepath):
        self.fp = open(filepath)
        cp = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
        cp.readfp(self)
        self.fp.close()
        return cp.items(self.secheadname)
```