# Reading file names from a properties file in python

Tags: python

I am reading from a text file and writing to a CSV using `DictWriter`. Now I want to implement the same code for several text files and write to different CSV files. I want to use a `properties.py` file for this purpose like:

```py
input1 = "file1.txt"  
output1 = "mycsv1.csv" 

input2 = "file2.txt"  
output2 = "mycsv2.csv"
```

and so on.

I tried using import and other methods specified in links such as "[what would be a quick way to read a property file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997777/what-would-be-a-quick-way-to-read-a-property-file-in-python)" and "[Using ConfigParser to read a file without section name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885190/using-configparser-to-read-a-file-without-section-name)", but could not solve this issue.

Part of my code:

```py
with open("mycsv1.csv") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['name', 'age', 'addr'], delimiter=',')
    writer.writeheader()
    with open("file1.txt") as fil:
    # rest of the operations
```

How can I change my code to make use of my `properties.py` file, i.e. each of the input files in the properties file are read one by one, and the output gets stored in the corresponding output csv?

Comment: Please provide input and desired output.

Comment: Do you know the names of the files or you will read them from a directory? I mean, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory

Comment: You say you "want to use a `properties.py` file for this purpose". Why? There are other file types you could use (like `.json`, `.ini` or `.xml`) which would make this task a lot easier - why do you want to use a `.py`?

Comment: @powerPixie from a directory

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `*args` in function definitions to help in this. In essence:

```py
def main(*args):
    for input in args:
        # Your code to run per file
        with open(input) as f:
            # etc etc etc
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

To use the above method, you now call it as:

```
main('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', ... , 'fileX.txt')
```

Things do change a bit if you are running `properties.py` as `python properties.py`. If so, then you can take advantage of either `sys.argv` (my personal preference) or `argparse` in your main function (reference: [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)).

The above would allow you to do this:

```
python properties.py input1.txt input2.txt ... inputX.txt
```

Comment: Instead of typing the names of the files in command line, can I store the names in some file and then use that instead in the command line?

Comment: @user12, definitely. You can also take that approach so the params for `python properties.py` would now be a file name (i.e., `python properties.py fileslist.txt`. Of course that would mean reading that input file with the list before the `for` loop.