# Python readline() from a string?

Tags: python

In python, is there a built-in way to do a readline() on string?  I have a large chunk of data and want to strip off just the first couple lines w/o doing split() on the whole string.

Hypothetical example:

```
def handleMessage(msg):
   headerTo  = msg.readline()
   headerFrom= msg.readline()
   sendMessage(headerTo,headerFrom,msg)

msg = "Bob Smith\nJane Doe\nJane,\nPlease order more widgets\nThanks,\nBob\n"
handleMessage(msg)
```

I want this to result in:
 `sendMessage("Bob Smith", "Jane Doe", "Jane,\nPlease order...")`

I know it would be fairly easy to write a class that does this, but I'm looking for something built-in if possible.

EDIT: Python v2.7

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In Python 3, you can use [io.StringIO](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```py
>>> msg = "Bob Smith\nJane Doe\nJane,\nPlease order more widgets\nThanks,\nBob\n"
>>> msg
'Bob Smith\nJane Doe\nJane,\nPlease order more widgets\nThanks,\nBob\n'
>>>
>>> import io
>>> buf = io.StringIO(msg)
>>> buf.readline()
'Bob Smith\n'
>>> buf.readline()
'Jane Doe\n'
>>> len(buf.read())
44
```

---

In Python 2, you can use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) (or [cStringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) if performance is important):

```py
>>> import StringIO
>>> buf = StringIO.StringIO(msg)
>>> buf.readline()
'Bob Smith\n'
>>> buf.readline()
'Jane Doe\n'
```

Comment: Perfect.  `buf.read()` what's left of the buffer after reading a certain number of lines.

Comment: Why allocating extra memory for buf?

Answer (score 40):

The easiest way for both python 2 and 3 is using string's method [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)(). This returns a list of lines.

```
>>> "some\nmultilene\nstring\n".splitlines()
```

['some', 'multilene', 'string']

Comment: And str.splitlines() is cross-platform, regardless the style of line endings like \r\n or \n.

Comment: I think that this is more convenient than the accepted answer.

Comment: the fun fact is that it removes all the `\n` or `\r\n`, so if you need to keep them as is, but split the lines, better go for the `StringIO` or put `keepend = True` arg in the splitlines()

Comment: @RatulHasan from doc: "str.splitlines(keepends=False)", set the keepends to True if you want to keep them.

Answer (score 21):

Why not just only do as many splits as you need? Since you're using all of the resulting parts (including the rest of the string), loading it into some other buffer object and then reading it back out again is probably going to be slower, not faster (plus the overhead of function calls).

If you want the first `N` lines separated out, just do `.split("\n", N)`.

```
>>> foo = "ABC\nDEF\nGHI\nJKL"
>>> foo.split("\n", 1)
['ABC', 'DEF\nGHI\nJKL']
>>> foo.split("\n", 2)
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI\nJKL']
```

So for your function:

```
def handleMessage(msg):
   headerTo, headerFrom, msg = msg.split("\n", 2)
   sendMessage(headerTo,headerFrom,msg)
```

or if you really wanted to get fancy:

```
# either...
def handleMessage(msg):
   sendMessage(*msg.split("\n", 2))

# or just...
handleMessage = lambda msg: sendMessage(*msg.split("\n", 2))
```

Comment: This works if you don't mind dealing with exceptions and/or checking array lengths that come with split AND you know how many lines to read in advance.  I don't know how many header lines there are in advance.  Perhaps my example was excessively trivial.

Comment: If you're inspecting things as you go, then yes, StringIO is probably your best bet. (No worries re: examples - constructing the appropriate example can often be a difficult balance between simplifying and not losing context.)

Answer (score 6):

Do it like StringIO does it:

```
i = self.buf.find('\n', self.pos)
```

So this means:

```
pos = msg.find("\n")
first_line = msg[:pos]
...
```

Seems more elegant than using the whole StringIO...

Answer (score 4):

in Python string have method splitlines

```
msg = "Bob Smith\nJane Doe\nJane,\nPlease order more widgets\nThanks,\nBob\n"
msg_splitlines = msg.splitlines()
headerTo = msg_splitlines[0]
headerFrom= msg_splitlines[1]
sendMessage(headerTo,headerFrom,msg)
```