# Properties file in python (similar to Java Properties)

Tags: python, properties, configparser

Given the following format (**.properties** or **.ini**):

```
propertyName1=propertyValue1
propertyName2=propertyValue2
...
propertyNameN=propertyValueN
```

For **Java** there is the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class that offers functionality to parse / interact with the above format.

Is there something similar in **python**'s **standard** library (2.x) ?

If not, what other alternatives do I have ?

Comment: This is not a Java question. Why did you rollback the Java tag removal?

Comment: You can check my post about Spring configuration alternative in python: https://code.massoudafrashteh.com/manage-dev-prod-config-in-python/

Comment: Maybe you could try https://pypi.org/project/property/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For `.ini` files there is the [`configparser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module that provides a format compatible with `.ini` files.

Anyway there's nothing available for parsing complete `.properties` files, when I have to do that I simply use jython (I'm talking about scripting).

Comment: pyjavaproperties seems to be an option if you don't want to use Jython: https://bitbucket.org/jnoller/pyjavaproperties

Comment: the java properties file is not equivalent to .ini file. pyjavaproperties is the right answer

Comment: Alex Matelli suggested a easy way to parse .properties files with ConfigParser here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2819788/15274

Comment: bitbucket.org/jnoller/pyjavaproperties hasn't been maintained since 2010. It is not compatible with python 3. I would use the solutions linked to by @pi.

Comment: Since nowhere here it is mentioned, let me add again that this is not the same. I cant speak for Java or Py3, and maybe it works for simple key/values. But the syntax for string interpolation is different.

This solution provides Python formatting, ie. %(string)s while (for e.g. Ant) I would use ${string}. https://pymotw.com/2/ConfigParser/

Comment: get we code, please?

Answer (score 98):

## Try ConfigParser

I was able to get this to work with `ConfigParser`, no one showed any examples on how to do this, so here is a simple python reader of a property file and example of the property file. Note that the extension is still `.properties`, but I had to add a section header similar to what you see in .ini files... a bit of a bastardization, but it works.

The python file: `PythonPropertyReader.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python    
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('ConfigFile.properties')

print config.get('DatabaseSection', 'database.dbname');
```

The property file: `ConfigFile.properties`

```ini
[DatabaseSection]
database.dbname=unitTest
database.user=root
database.password=
```

For more functionality, read: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: The ConfigParser module has been renamed to configparser in Python 3.

Comment: This is for .ini files, not .properties files as they do not contain sections, and configParser fails if it doesn't find any section header. Moreover, ini files may not include sections so this configParser doesn't seem reliable at all

Answer (score 79):

I know that this is a very old question, but I need it just now and I decided to implement my own solution, a pure python solution, that covers most uses cases (not all):

```
def load_properties(filepath, sep='=', comment_char='#'):
    """
    Read the file passed as parameter as a properties file.
    """
    props = {}
    with open(filepath, "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            l = line.strip()
            if l and not l.startswith(comment_char):
                key_value = l.split(sep)
                key = key_value[0].strip()
                value = sep.join(key_value[1:]).strip().strip('"') 
                props[key] = value 
    return props
```

You can change the `sep` to ':' to parse files with format:

```
key : value
```

The code parses correctly lines like:

```
url = "http://my-host.com"
name = Paul = Pablo
# This comment line will be ignored
```

You'll get a dict with:

```
{"url": "http://my-host.com", "name": "Paul = Pablo" }
```

Comment: Top notch solution and is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note that this doesn't support comments on the same line as the entries like `foo = "bar" # bat`.

Comment: @ThomasW If we're using Java as the de-facto standard, Properties#load will treat that as a property `foo` with value `"bar" # bat`.

Comment: You thought what's the point in posting answer to an old question? The point is I was able to save time by just copy paste this, in one of my azure pipeline rather than implementing it myself. so thanks :)

Comment: Love the answer!  The only change I made to handle inline comments was to change `l = line.strip()` to `l = line.split(comment_char)[0].strip()` and then only check if `l` has a value rather on the subsequent line with `if l:`.

Comment: It's not so simple, for instance, this case will fail: `my.key = "text with # inside" # This is an example`

Comment: +1 Ignoring those fancy inline comments, it could be simplified with `key_value = l.split(sep, 1)` and then `value = key_value[1].strip().strip('"')`.

Answer (score 66):

A java properties file is often valid python code as well.  You could rename your myconfig.properties file to myconfig.py. Then just import your file, like this

```
import myconfig
```

and access the properties directly

```
print myconfig.propertyName1
```

Comment: Not a bad idea.. should be `import myconfig` though, without the `.py`

Comment: I like the idea, but it does not work for properties that contain dots, i.e. `prop.name="val"` is not going to work in this case.

Comment: `A java properties file is valid python code`: I have to differ. *Some* Java properties files will pass for valid python code, but certainly not all. As @mmjj said dots are a problem. So are unquoted literal strings. -1.

Comment: A Rather Bad Idea... since it is broken.  Java prop files allow ":" instead of "="; they eat whitespace after line-continuations; they don't quote strings.  None of that is "valid Python".

Comment: Java properties files are in general not going to pass for valid python code.  One alternative is to just set your properties in a python file, and use valid python (e.g: MEDIA_ROOT='/foo') ...

Comment: Properties files do not include quotes around values, so the two syntaxes are incompatible. If you just need a simple config file for Python, then yes you can use Python syntax where in Java you would use a .properties, but if you need to parse a Java-compatible file, this will not work.

Comment: This is a hack best avoided.  You're going to have a bad day when you're properties change and the file is no longer valid python.

Comment: This is a really bad idea - it is a big secutiry flaw. A property file containing malicious code could cause unforeseen consequences.

Comment: This is a really bad idea, as @DanH mentioned - properties are definitely not valid Python code, and this is a HUGE security vulnerability if these property files are coming from an external source, or if users are allowed to modify them

Answer (score 20):

if you don't have multi line properties and a very simple need, a few lines of code can solve it for you:

File `t.properties`:

```
a=b
c=d
e=f
```

Python code:

```
with open("t.properties") as f:
    l = [line.split("=") for line in f.readlines()]
    d = {key.strip(): value.strip() for key, value in l}
```

Comment: Thanks, straightforward as I like !

Answer (score 17):

If you have an option of file formats I suggest using .ini and Python's ConfigParser as mentioned.  If you need compatibility with Java .properties files I have written a library for it called [jprops](https://github.com/mgood/jprops/).  We were using pyjavaproperties, but after encountering various limitations I ended up implementing my own.  It has full support for the .properties format, including unicode support and better support for escape sequences.  Jprops can also parse any file-like object while pyjavaproperties only works with real files on disk.

Comment: I just gave this a try.  Works like a charm. +1 for MattGood!

Comment: if you add pip install and a code example your answer will be even better           
pip install jprops,                                                                                                   
with open(path) as fp:
        properties = jprops.load_properties(fp)

        print(properties)

Answer (score 7):

i have used this, this library is very useful

```
from pyjavaproperties import Properties
p = Properties()
p.load(open('test.properties'))
p.list()
print(p)
print(p.items())
print(p['name3'])
p['name3'] = 'changed = value'
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not exactly properties but Python does have a [nice library](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) for parsing configuration files. Also see this recipe: [A python replacement for java.util.Properties](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496795-a-python-replacement-for-javautilproperties/).

Comment: For the second link...This is no longer developed actively. Jesse noller has created a project from this recipe with some fixes not available here. Author recommends that project to anyone using this recipe. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjavaproperties

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496795-a-python-replacement-for-javautilproperties/) is a one-to-one replacement of java.util.Propeties

From the doc:

```
  def __parse(self, lines):
        """ Parse a list of lines and create
        an internal property dictionary """

        # Every line in the file must consist of either a comment
        # or a key-value pair. A key-value pair is a line consisting
        # of a key which is a combination of non-white space characters
        # The separator character between key-value pairs is a '=',
        # ':' or a whitespace character not including the newline.
        # If the '=' or ':' characters are found, in the line, even
        # keys containing whitespace chars are allowed.

        # A line with only a key according to the rules above is also
        # fine. In such case, the value is considered as the empty string.
        # In order to include characters '=' or ':' in a key or value,
        # they have to be properly escaped using the backslash character.

        # Some examples of valid key-value pairs:
        #
        # key     value
        # key=value
        # key:value
        # key     value1,value2,value3
        # key     value1,value2,value3 \
        #         value4, value5
        # key
        # This key= this value
        # key = value1 value2 value3

        # Any line that starts with a '#' is considerered a comment
        # and skipped. Also any trailing or preceding whitespaces
        # are removed from the key/value.

        # This is a line parser. It parses the
        # contents like by line.
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is link to my project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyproperties/. It is a library with methods for working with *.properties files for Python 3.x.

But it is not based on java.util.Properties

Answer (score 3):

You can use a file-like object in `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.readfp` defined here -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.readfp

Define a class that overrides `readline` that adds a section name before the actual contents of your properties file.

I've packaged it into the class that returns a `dict` of all the properties defined.

```
import ConfigParser

class PropertiesReader(object):

    def __init__(self, properties_file_name):
        self.name = properties_file_name
        self.main_section = 'main'

        # Add dummy section on top
        self.lines = [ '[%s]\n' % self.main_section ]

        with open(properties_file_name) as f:
            self.lines.extend(f.readlines())

        # This makes sure that iterator in readfp stops
        self.lines.append('')

    def readline(self):
        return self.lines.pop(0)

    def read_properties(self):
        config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

        # Without next line the property names will be lowercased
        config.optionxform = str

        config.readfp(self)
        return dict(config.items(self.main_section))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print PropertiesReader('/path/to/file.properties').read_properties()
```

Answer (score 3):

create a dictionary in your python module and store everything into it and access it, for example:

```
dict = {
       'portalPath' : 'www.xyx.com',
       'elementID': 'submit'}
```

Now to access it you can simply do:

```
submitButton = driver.find_element_by_id(dict['elementID'])
```

Comment: It is highly recommended to share some code sample. For now your answer is very poor

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko sorry for poor formatting , I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

My Java ini files didn't have section headers and I wanted a dict as a result. So i simply injected an "[ini]" section and let the default config library do its job.

Take a version.ini fie of the eclipse IDE .metadata directory as an example:

```
#Mon Dec 20 07:35:29 CET 2021
org.eclipse.core.runtime=2
org.eclipse.platform=4.19.0.v20210303-1800
```

```
# 'injected' ini section
[ini]
#Mon Dec 20 07:35:29 CET 2021
org.eclipse.core.runtime=2
org.eclipse.platform=4.19.0.v20210303-1800
```

The result is converted to a dict:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser

@staticmethod
    def readPropertyFile(path):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595363/properties-file-in-python-similar-to-java-properties
        config = ConfigParser()
        s_config= open(path, 'r').read()
        s_config="[ini]\n%s" % s_config
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841741/1497139
        config.read_string(s_config)
        items=config.items('ini')
        itemDict={}
        for key,value in items:
            itemDict[key]=value
        return itemDict
```

Comment: injected an [ini]?  What does that mean?  Please show your config file.

Comment: @johnktejik - please find an example added as requested

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm doing in my project: I just create another .py file called properties.py which includes all common variables/properties I used in the project, and in any file need to refer to these variables, put

```
from properties import *(or anything you need)
```

Used this method to keep svn peace when I was changing dev locations frequently and some common variables were quite relative to local environment. Works fine for me but not sure this method would be suggested for formal dev environment etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a python module that is almost similar to the Properties class of Java ( Actually it is like the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in spring which lets you use ${variable-reference} to refer to already defined property )

EDIT : You may install this package by running the command(currently tested for python 3).
 `pip install property`

The project is hosted on [GitHub](http://anandjoshi91.github.io/pythonpropertyfileloader/)

Example :  ( Detailed documentation can be found [here](http://pythonhosted.org/property/) )

Let's say you have the following properties defined in my_file.properties file

```
foo = I am awesome
bar = ${chocolate}-bar
chocolate = fudge
```

Code to load the above properties

```
from properties.p import Property

prop = Property()
# Simply load it into a dictionary
dic_prop = prop.load_property_files('my_file.properties')
```

Comment: Let's say you have the following properties defined in my_file.properties file

foo = I am awesome
bar = ${chocolate}-bar
chocolate = fudge

Code to load the above properties

prop = Property()
prop.load('path/to/my_file.properties')
prop.get('foo') # I am awesome
prop.get('bar') # fudge-bar

Comment: Done . Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
f=open('test.json')
x=json.load(f)
f.close()
print(x)
```

Contents of test.json:
{"host": "127.0.0.1", "user": "jms"}

Answer (score 2):

If you need to read all values from a section in properties file in a simple manner:

Your `config.properties` file layout :

```
[SECTION_NAME]  
key1 = value1  
key2 = value2
```

You code:

```
   import configparser

   config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
   config.read('path_to_config.properties file')

   details_dict = dict(config.items('SECTION_NAME'))
```

This will give you a dictionary where keys are same as in config file and their corresponding values.

`details_dict` is :

```
{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}
```

Now to get key1's value :
    `details_dict['key1']`

Putting it all in a method which reads that section from config file only once(the first time the method is called during a program run).

```
def get_config_dict():
    if not hasattr(get_config_dict, 'config_dict'):
        get_config_dict.config_dict = dict(config.items('SECTION_NAME'))
    return get_config_dict.config_dict
```

Now call the above function and get the required key's value :

```
config_details = get_config_dict()
key_1_value = config_details['key1']
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------

Extending the approach mentioned above, reading section by section automatically and then accessing by section name followed by key name.

```
def get_config_section():
    if not hasattr(get_config_section, 'section_dict'):
        get_config_section.section_dict = dict()

        for section in config.sections():
            get_config_section.section_dict[section] = 
                             dict(config.items(section))

    return get_config_section.section_dict
```

**To access:**

```
config_dict = get_config_section()

port = config_dict['DB']['port']
```

(here 'DB' is a section name in config file 
    and 'port' is a key under section 'DB'.)

Answer (score 1):

Below 2 lines of code shows how to use Python List Comprehension to load 'java style' property file.

```
split_properties=[line.split("=") for line in open('/<path_to_property_file>)]
properties={key: value for key,value in split_properties }
```

Please have a look at below post for details
https://ilearnonlinesite.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/reading-property-file-in-python-using-comprehension-and-generators/

Comment: The code doesn't close the file object, also link only answer is not welcome.

Comment: That solution does not cover multi-line values or values that include an equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

you can use parameter "fromfile_prefix_chars" with argparse to read from config file as below---

**temp.py**

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='#')
parser.add_argument('--a')
parser.add_argument('--b')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.a)
print(args.b)
```

**config file**

```
--a
hello
--b
hello dear
```

**Run command**

```
python temp.py "#config"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use - https://pypi.org/project/property/

eg - `my_file.properties`

```
foo = I am awesome
bar = ${chocolate}-bar
chocolate = fudge
long = a very long property that is described in the property file which takes up \
multiple lines can be defined by the escape character as it is done here
url=example.com/api?auth_token=xyz
user_dir=${HOME}/test
unresolved = ${HOME}/files/${id}/${bar}/
fname_template = /opt/myapp/{arch}/ext/{objid}.dat
```

Code

```
from properties.p import Property


## set use_env to evaluate properties from shell / os environment
prop = Property(use_env = True)
dic_prop = prop.load_property_files('my_file.properties')

## Read multiple files
## dic_prop = prop.load_property_files('file1', 'file2')


print(dic_prop)

# Output

# {'foo': 'I am awesome', 'bar': 'fudge-bar', 'chocolate': 'fudge',
#  'long': 'a very long property that is described in the property file which takes up multiple lines
#  can be defined by the escape character as it is done here', 'url': 'example.com/api?auth_token=xyz',
#  'user_dir': '/home/user/test',
#  'unresolved': '/home/user/files/${id}/fudge-bar/',
#  'fname_template': '/opt/myapp/{arch}/ext/{objid}.dat'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using ConfigParser as follows. The code assumes that there is a file called `config.prop` in the same directory where `BaseTest.py` is placed:

`config.prop`:

```ini
[CredentialSection]
app.name=MyAppName
```

`BaseTest.py`:

```py
import unittest
import ConfigParser

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        __SECTION = 'CredentialSection'
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.readfp(open('config.prop'))
        self.__app_name = config.get(__SECTION, 'app.name')
    
    def test1(self):
        print self.__app_name % This should print: MyAppName
```

Answer (score 0):

This is  what i had written to parse file and set it as env variables  which skips comments and non key value lines added switches  to specify 
 hg:d

- -h or --help print usage summary
- -c Specify char that identifies comment
- -s Separator between key and value in prop file
- and specify properties file that needs to be parsed eg :   python
  EnvParamSet.py  -c # -s =  env.properties

  ```
  import pipes
  import sys , getopt
  import os.path

  class Parsing :

          def __init__(self , seprator , commentChar , propFile):
          self.seprator = seprator
          self.commentChar = commentChar
          self.propFile  = propFile

      def  parseProp(self):
          prop = open(self.propFile,'rU')
          for line in prop :
              if line.startswith(self.commentChar)==False and  line.find(self.seprator) != -1  :
                  keyValue = line.split(self.seprator)
                  key =  keyValue[0].strip() 
                  value = keyValue[1].strip() 
                          print("export  %s=%s" % (str (key),pipes.quote(str(value))))




  class EnvParamSet:

      def main (argv):

          seprator = '='
          comment =  '#'

          if len(argv)  is 0:
              print "Please Specify properties file to be parsed "
              sys.exit()
          propFile=argv[-1] 


          try :
              opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hs:c:f:", ["help", "seprator=","comment=", "file="])
          except getopt.GetoptError,e:
              print str(e)
              print " possible  arguments  -s <key value sperator > -c < comment char >    <file> \n  Try -h or --help "
              sys.exit(2)


          if os.path.isfile(args[0])==False:
              print "File doesnt exist "
              sys.exit()


          for opt , arg  in opts :
              if opt in ("-h" , "--help"):
                  print " hg:d  \n -h or --help print usage summary \n -c Specify char that idetifes comment  \n -s Sperator between key and value in prop file \n  specify file  "
                  sys.exit()
              elif opt in ("-s" , "--seprator"):
                  seprator = arg 
              elif opt in ("-c"  , "--comment"):
                  comment  = arg

          p = Parsing( seprator, comment , propFile)
          p.parseProp()

      if __name__ == "__main__":
              main(sys.argv[1:])
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Lightbend has released the [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) library, which parses properties files and also some JSON-based extensions. Lightbend's library is only for the JVM, but it seems to be widely adopted and there are now ports in many languages, including Python: https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function, which is the modified code of @mvallebr. It respects the properties file comments, ignores empty new lines, and allows retrieving a single key value.

```
def getProperties(propertiesFile ="/home/memin/.config/customMemin/conf.properties", key=''):
    """
    Reads a .properties file and returns the key value pairs as dictionary.
    if key value is specified, then it will return its value alone.
    """
    with open(propertiesFile) as f:
        l = [line.strip().split("=") for line in f.readlines() if not line.startswith('#') and line.strip()]
        d = {key.strip(): value.strip() for key, value in l}

        if key:
            return d[key]
        else:
            return d
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
from pyjavaproperties import Properties
p = Properties()
p.load(open('test.properties'))
p.list()
print p
print p.items()
print p['name3']
```

Comment: Please remove this duplicate posting. btw I did upvote your other one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I followed configparser approach and it worked quite well for me. Created one PropertyReader file and used config parser there to ready property to corresponding to each section.

**Used Python 2.7

Content of PropertyReader.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ConfigParser

class PropertyReader:

def readProperty(self, strSection, strKey):
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('ConfigFile.properties')
    strValue = config.get(strSection,strKey);
    print "Value captured for "+strKey+" :"+strValue
    return strValue
```

Content of read schema file:

```
from PropertyReader import *

class ReadSchema:

print PropertyReader().readProperty('source1_section','source_name1')
print PropertyReader().readProperty('source2_section','sn2_sc1_tb')
```

Content of  .properties file:

```
[source1_section]
source_name1:module1
sn1_schema:schema1,schema2,schema3
sn1_sc1_tb:employee,department,location
sn1_sc2_tb:student,college,country

[source2_section]
source_name1:module2
sn2_schema:schema4,schema5,schema6
sn2_sc1_tb:employee,department,location
sn2_sc2_tb:student,college,country
```

Comment: This is an ini file, properties file will not have no section headers

Comment: doesnt seem to work with python 3?  I get `AttributeError: type object 'ConfigParser' has no attribute 'RawConfigParser'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `python-dotenv` library. This library reads key-value pairs from a `.env` (so not exactly a `.properties` file though) file and can set them as environment variables.

Here's a sample usage from the [official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/):

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # take environment variables from .env.

# Code of your application, which uses environment variables (e.g. from `os.environ` or
# `os.getenv`) as if they came from the actual environment.
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing on the [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263269/1008880) of @mvallebr:

```
def readConfig(filepath: str, delim: str = '=') -> dict:
    try:
        with open(filepath) as f:
            l = [line.split("=") for ln in f.readlines() \
                 if (line := ln.strip()) and not line.startswith('#')]
            return {key.strip().strip('"'): value.strip().strip('"') for key, value in l}
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)
```