# Jython - importing a text file to assign global variables

Tags: jython

I am using Jython and wish to import a text file that contains many configuration values such as:

```
QManager = MYQM
ProdDBName = MYDATABASE
```

etc.

.. and then I am reading the file line by line.

What I am unable to figure out is now that as I read each line and have assigned whatever is before the = sign to a local loop variable named `MYVAR` and assigned whatever is after the = sign to a local loop variable `MYVAL` - how do I ensure that once the loop finishes I have a bunch of global variables such as `QManager` & `ProdDBName` etc.

I've been working on this for days - I really hope someone can help.

Many thanks,
Bret.

Comment: related: [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via to a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5036700/4279)

Answer (score 1):

See other question: [Properties file in python (similar to Java Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595363/properties-file-in-python-similar-to-java-properties)

Automatically setting global variables is not a good idea for me. I would prefer global `ConfigParser` object or dictionary. If your config file is similar to Windows `.ini` files then you can read it and set some global variables with something like:

```
def read_conf():
    global QManager
    import ConfigParser
    conf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    conf.read('my.conf')
    QManager = conf.get('QM', 'QManager')
    print('Conf option QManager: [%s]' % (QManager))
```

(this assumes you have `[QM]` section in your `my.conf` config file)

If you want to parse config file without help of `ConfigParser` or similar module then try:

```
my_options = {}
f = open('my.conf')
for line in f:
    if '=' in line:
        k, v = line.split('=', 1)
        k = k.strip()
        v = v.strip()
        print('debug [%s]:[%s]' % (k, v))
        my_options[k] = v
f.close()
print('-' * 20)
# this will show just read value
print('Option QManager: [%s]' % (my_options['QManager']))
# this will fail with KeyError exception
# you must be aware of non-existing values or values
# where case differs
print('Option qmanager: [%s]' % (my_options['qmanager']))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice.  I can now do what I wanted. To make things tidier - how would I loop through each line of my config file and set the configuration options without knowing what configuration options were in the config file?

Comment: +1: a dict, ConfigParser, pyjavaproperties or java.util.Properties is the way to go.