# How to read config from string or list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

Is it possible to read the configuration for `ConfigParser` from a string or list?
Without any kind of temporary file on a filesystem

**OR**
Is there any similar solution for this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could use a buffer which behaves like a file:
**Python 3** solution

```
import configparser
import io

s_config = """
[example]
is_real: False
"""
buf = io.StringIO(s_config)
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_file(buf)
print(config.getboolean('example', 'is_real'))
```

In **Python 2.7**, this implementation was correct:

```
import ConfigParser
import StringIO

s_config = """
[example]
is_real: False
"""
buf = StringIO.StringIO(s_config)
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(buf)
print config.getboolean('example', 'is_real')
```

Comment: well where to use the buffer? ConfigParser.Read() excepts a file name.

Comment: [`cStringIO` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) are not [`buffer`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer). _Strings_ are buffers, but buffers cannot be used where `file`-like objects are required; `cStringIO` _wraps_ a `buffer` in order to make it behave like a `file`. Besides, your example does not demonstrate how a `cStringIO` behaves like a file; `getvalue` is a method specific to `cStringIO` instances, but files don't have it.

Comment: @Lucas I've posted a complete example that takes a StringIO buffer and gets a sample value

Comment: Note that `config.readfp` is deprecated in favor of `config.read_file` [as of Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file)

Answer (score 35):

The question was tagged as python-2.7 but just for the sake of completeness: Since 3.2 you can use the [ConfigParser function read_string()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_string) so you don't need the StringIO method anymore.

```
import configparser

s_config = """
[example]
is_real: False
"""
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_string(s_config)
print(config.getboolean('example', 'is_real'))
```

Comment: 1 more reason I hate working with Python 2.7 still (thanks RHEL 7)

Comment: To be fair to RHEL7, it's perfectly possibly to install Python 3.x.  https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/

Answer (score 1):

Python has `read_string` and `read_dict` since version 3.2. It does not support reading from lists.

The example shows reading from a dictionary. Keys are section names, values are dictionaries with keys and values that should be present in the section.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import configparser

cfg_data = {
    'mysql': {'host': 'localhost', 'user': 'user7',
              'passwd': 's$cret', 'db': 'ydb'}
}

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_dict(cfg_data)

host = config['mysql']['host']
user = config['mysql']['user']
passwd = config['mysql']['passwd']
db = config['mysql']['db']

print(f'Host: {host}')
print(f'User: {user}')
print(f'Password: {passwd}')
print(f'Database: {db}')
```