# Pyspark: Reading properties files on HDFS using configParser

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I am using ConfigParser to read through key values which are passed to my pyspark program. The code works fine when I execute from edge node of a hadoop cluster,with the config file in local directory of edge node. This doesn't if the config file is uploaded to a hdfs path and I try accessing the same using the parser.

The config file  para.conf has below contents

```
[tracker]
port=9801
```

On local client mode, with para.conf in local directory, to access the values i am using the below.

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read("para.conf")
myport = parser.get('tracker', 'port')
```

The above works fine...

On Hadoop Cluster : 
Uploaded para.conf file to hdfs directory path bdc/para.conf

```
parser.read("hdfs://clusternamenode:8020/bdc/para.conf")
```

this doesn't return anythin, neither does the below by escaping..

```
parser.read("hdfs:///clusternamenode:8020//bdc//para.conf")
```

Although using sqlCOntext i can read this file which returns a valid rdd.

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://clusternamenode:8020/bdc/para.conf")
```

though am not sure if using configParser can extract the key values from this..

Can anyone advise if configParser can be used to read files from hdfs ? Or is there any alternative ?

Comment: The problem is that ConfigParser can't handle hdfs file paths. What you could do is implementing your own configreader or read with `bla = sc.textFile("hdfs://clusternamenode:8020/bdc/para.conf").collect()` which gives you a list of strings. The configreader can handle strings with [read_string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_string).

Comment: read_string is not option as I am using Python 2.7+  . Tried using  as sugested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766451/how-to-read-config-from-string-or-list                              
buf = StringIO.StringIO(s_config)
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(buf)                                                                        But this gives a no Section error !

Comment: Can you please extend your question with the code you have used and complete error message  you have got?

Comment: Using read_string option
    import ConfigParser
    credstr = sc.textFile("hdfs://clusternamenode:8020/bdc/cre.conf").collect()
    parse_str=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    parse_str.read_string(credstr)
Error received : AttributeError: ConfigParser instance has no attribute 'read_string'

Comment: Using File buffer option
   ` import ConfigParser
    import StringIO
    credstr = sc.textFile("hdfs://clusternamenode:8020/bdc/cre.conf").collect()
    buf = StringIO.StringIO(credstr)
    parse_str = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    parse_str.readfp(buf)
    parse_str.get('tracker','port') `
Error received :-
raise NoSectionError(section) ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'tracker'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have copied most of the code you have provided in the comments. You were really close to the solution. Your problem was that [sc.textFile](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile) produces a row in the rdd for every newline character. When you call .collect() you get a list of strings for every line of your document. The StringIO is not expecting a list, it is expecting a string and therefore you have to restore the previous document structure from your list. See working example below:

```py
import ConfigParser 
import StringIO 
credstr = sc.textFile("hdfs://clusternamenode:8020/bdc/cre.conf").collect() 
buf = StringIO.StringIO("\n".join(credstr)) 
parse_str = ConfigParser.ConfigParser() 
parse_str.readfp(buf) 
parse_str.get('tracker','port')
```

Output:

```py
'9801'
```

Comment: Awesome ! this works :)    I found  quite a bad solution by taking the list elements and substring the same to get my value ....! Will use this one now.. thanks !..