# Bytes conversion to string for use in ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser, dataiku

I am using DataIku to read in a file, which is config.txt.

I am getting a "bytes" object back, and need to convert it into a string to send to configparser.

It looks a bit like this:

```
b"[email]\r\nsender = fred@somewhere.com.com\r\nreceiver = someoneelse@somewhere.com\r\nsubject = weekly email"
```

I am trying to convert it to a string:

```
data_string = str(data,"utf-8")
```

But this just gives me the same represenation, but without the "b" prefix.

```
"[email]\r\nsender = fred@somewhere.com.com\r\nreceiver = someoneelse@somewhere.com\r\nsubject = weekly email"
```

When I try to pass this into the read() method of configparser, it doesn't recognise the config as valid, as it can't find the sections [Email] for example.

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(data_string)

input_file = config.get("email", "sender")
input_file
```

It fails miserably, likely because of the "\r\n" content of the string.

```
/usr/lib64/python3.6/configparser.py in _unify_values(self, section, vars)
   1139         except KeyError:
   1140             if section != self.default_section:
-> 1141                 raise NoSectionError(section)
   1142         # Update with the entry specific variables
   1143         vardict = {}

NoSectionError: No section: 'email'
```

How can I take a bytes object of a string, and just convert it into a normal string that configparser will accept?

I tried passing in the raw bytes object also into configparser.read(), which it supports, but this just killed the Kernel every time in the notebook.

Edit:

They closed this issue because apparently it has been answered 23 times before.  None of those solutions work for me, decode() or str("utf-8") solve the problem.  Why close the question down when my issue has not been resolved?

Comment: Your problem isn't converting the bytes object into a string. The problem is that you are using `config.read()` incorrectly. The argument of that method is a *filename*, not the string containing the configuration text. You want `config.read_string()` instead.

Comment: This works:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766451/how-to-read-config-from-string-or-list, as does read_string().  See, I knew they shouldn;t have closed the question. Thanks!

Comment: Your question was misleading, because you mistakenly indicated that it was about converting a bytes object to a string, so it looked very much like a question that had long since been asked and answered. Next time, when you ask a question, don't jump to conclusions about the source of your problem.