# I want to read from Properties file and put that value in a string based on a key from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, properties

I am new learning python and I have to deal with the properties file in that file the value will be present in key value pair and some how I think managed to readFile but not able to store or print the value based on a key.

I have tried with the jproperties libraries installed through pip.I have read the values in the object but unable to fetch the records from it.
Have gone through [https://pypi.org/project/jproperties/](https://pypi.org/project/jproperties/#parsing-a-property-file)#parsing-a-property-file website for reference

```
from jproperties import Properties

class PropertiesReader:
    p = Properties()
    with open("foobar.properties", "rt") as f:
        p.load(f, "utf-8")

    s = p.__getitem__("name","value")
    z = p.__getattribute__("email","mail")
    print(s)
    print(z)
```

and the properties file

```
foobar.properties
    name = Harsh
    email = abc.xyz
```

and the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harshk/PycharmProjects/demoPythonPOC/scratch.py", line 4, in <module>
    class PropertiesReader:
  File "/home/harshk/PycharmProjects/demoPythonPOC/scratch.py", line 7, in PropertiesReader
    p.load(f, "utf-8")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 804, in load
    self._parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 731, in _parse
    while self._parse_logical_line():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 686, in _parse_logical_line
    self._skip_whitespace()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 438, in _skip_whitespace
    c = self._peek()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jproperties.py", line 378, in _peek
    c = self._source_file.read(1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 500, in read
    data = self.bytebuffer + newdata
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to print like

```
Harsh
abc.xyz
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properties file in python (similar to Java Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595363/properties-file-in-python-similar-to-java-properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test below code :  https://repl.it/repls/EmptyRowdyCategories

```
from jproperties import Properties

p = Properties()
with open("foobar.properties", "rb") as f:
    p.load(f, "utf-8")


print(p["name"].data)
print(p["email"].data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're opening the file as if it's a text file:

```
with open("foobar.properties", "rt") as f:
    p.load(f, "utf-8")
```

But the [jproperties docs](https://pypi.org/project/jproperties/#parsing-a-property-file) shows that you need to open the file in binary mode:

```
with open("foobar.properties", "rb") as f:
    p.load(f, "utf-8")
```