# Dictionary from a String with particular structure

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am using python 3 to read this file and convert it to a dictionary.

I have this string from a file and I would like to know how could be possible to create a dictionary from it.

```
[User]
Date=10/26/2003
Time=09:01:01 AM
User=teodor
UserText=Max Cor
UserTextUnicode=392039n9dj90j32

[System]
Type=Absolute
Dnumber=QS236
Software=1.1.1.2
BuildNr=0923875
Source=LAM
Column=OWKD

[Build]
StageX=12345
Spotter=2
ApertureX=0.0098743
ApertureY=0.2431899
ShiftXYZ=-4.234809e-002

[Text]
Text=Here is the Text files
DataBaseNumber=The database number is 918723
```

**..... (There are more than 1000 lines per file) ...**

On the text I have `"Name=Something"` and then I would like to convert it as follows:

```
{'Date':'10/26/2003',
'Time':'09:01:01 AM'
'User':'teodor'
'UserText':'Max Cor'
'UserTextUnicode':'392039n9dj90j32'.......}
```

The word between `[ ]` can be removed, like `[User], [System], [Build], [Text], etc...`

In some fields there is only the first part of the string:

```
[Colors]
Red=
Blue=
Yellow=
DarkBlue=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can easily be done in python. Assuming your file is named `test.txt`.
This will also work for lines with nothing after the `=` as well as lines with multiple `=`.

```py
d = {}
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() # Remove any space or newline characters
        parts = line.split('=') # Split around the `=`
        if len(parts) > 1:
            d[parts[0]] = ''.join(parts[1:])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{
  "Date": "10/26/2003",
  "Time": "09:01:01 AM",
  "User": "teodor",
  "UserText": "Max Cor",
  "UserTextUnicode": "392039n9dj90j32",
  "Type": "Absolute",
  "Dnumber": "QS236",
  "Software": "1.1.1.2",
  "BuildNr": "0923875",
  "Source": "LAM",
  "Column": "OWKD",
  "StageX": "12345",
  "Spotter": "2",
  "ApertureX": "0.0098743",
  "ApertureY": "0.2431899",
  "ShiftXYZ": "-4.234809e-002",
  "Text": "Here is the Text files",
  "DataBaseNumber": "The database number is 918723"
}
```

Comment: If it solved the answer dont forget to mark it is an answer :). Though the config parser pay work better.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an ordinary [properties file](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/). You can use this example to read the values into map:

```java
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("your_file_path")) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);

    // prop.getProperty("User") == "teodor"

} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT:**
For Python solution, refer to [the answerred question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595363/properties-file-in-python-similar-to-java-properties).
You can use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) to read `.ini`, or `.properties` files (format you have).

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('your_file_path')

# config['User'] == {'Date': '10/26/2003', 'Time': '09:01:01 AM'...}
# config['User']['User'] == 'teodor'
# config['System'] == {'Type': 'Abosulte', ...}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to say that I am using python :( - I will read the link that you sent me

Comment: @Alambek no problem. :) The solution is more or less the same (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595363/properties-file-in-python-similar-to-java-properties)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do some cleaning to get rid of the [] lines.

After that you can split those lines by the "=" separator and then convert it to a dictionary.