# How to import a function into a .properties file

Tags: python, application.properties

I have a `.properties` file that sets up some configurations for calling passwords. However, rather than hardcoding the `username` and `passwords` I wanted to use some variables to call another py file that holds a functions that calls for the those very things.

.properties file:

```
ex.environment.config=IT
ex.client.id=
ex.client.secret=
```

.py file functions calling for username and password:

```
def get_client_id(self):
        return self.config.get('EX_CLIENT_ID', '')

def get_client_password(self):
        return self.config.get('EX_CLIENT_SECRET', '')
```

How do I make the `ex.client.id` variable reference my function from my `.py` file? This is the way my director is wanting us to hide username and passwords

Comment: `.properties` is not an executable file, you cannot have a function in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Properties file in python (similar to Java Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595363/properties-file-in-python-similar-to-java-properties)