# How to create a dictionary that contains key‐value pairs from a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file (one.txt) that contains an arbitrary number of key‐value pairs (where the key and value are separated by a colon – e.g., x:17). Here are some (minus the numbers):

1. mattis:turpis
2. Aliquam:adipiscing
3. nonummy:ligula
4. Duis:ultricies
5. nonummy:pretium
6. urna:dolor
7. odio:mauris
8. lectus:per
9. quam:ridiculus
10. tellus:nonummy
11. consequat:metus

I need to open the file and create a dictionary that contains all of the key‐value pairs.

So far I have opened the file with

```
file = []
with open('one.txt', 'r') as _:
    for line in _:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            file.append(line)
```

I opened it this way to get rid of new line characters and the last black line in the text file. I am given a list of the key-value pairs within python.

I am not sure how to create a dictionary with the list key-value pairs.
Everything I have tried gives me an error. Some say something along the lines of

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.split()`:

```
with open('one.txt') as f:
    d = dict(l.strip().split(':') for l in f)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! And it it is a lot more concise.

Answer (score 2):

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?#str.split) will allow you to specify the separator `:` to separate the key and value into separate strings.  Then you can use them to populate a dictionary, for example: `mydict`

```
mydict = {}
with open('one.txt', 'r') as _:
    for line in _:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            mydict[key] = value
print mydict
```

output:

```
{'mattis': 'turpis', 'lectus': 'per', 'tellus': 'nonummy', 'quam': 'ridiculus', 'Duis': 'ultricies', 'consequat': 'metus', 'nonummy': 'pretium', 'odio': 'mauris', 'urna': 'dolor', 'Aliquam': 'adipiscing'}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I did not realize how simple of a fix my script would be to make it into dictionaries. I am new to programming and have been working on this one part for most of the day. Thank you thank you!