# Read Value from Config File Python

Tags: python, configuration, environment-variables

I have a file `.env` file contain 5 lines

```
DB_HOST=http://localhost/
DB_DATABASE=bheng-local
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234567890
UNIX_SOCKET=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

I want to write python to grab the value of **DB_DATABASE**
I want this `bheng-local`

---

I would have use

```
import linecache
print linecache.getline('.env', 2)
```

But some people might change the order of the cofigs, that's why linecache is not my option.

---

I am not sure how to check for only some strings match but all the entire line, and grab the value after the `=`.

I'm kind of stuck here :

```
file = open('.env', "r")
read = file.read()
my_line = ""

for line in read.splitlines():
    if line == "DB_DATABASE=":
        my_line = line
        break
print my_line
```

Can someone please give me a little push here ?

Comment: the `startwith` may be of assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the config parser:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

It's more elegant than a self-made solution

Comment: I like the idea of using the parser, but it require me to add more texts on top of my configs file. I don't mind if I am the only one that has it. This config file s is deployed to thousand people already. :( Is there a simple way to grab it base on DB_DATABASE which is the string of file ?

Comment: There are some hacks to go around it, you can find them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819696/parsing-properties-file-in-python/): 
The shortest is probably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25493615/3022712) , for Python 3.2+ and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8657601/3022712) for earlier versions. The most elegant probably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2819788/3022712).

Answer (score 10):

Modify your .env to

```
[DB]
DB_HOST=http://localhost/
DB_DATABASE=bheng-local
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234567890
UNIX_SOCKET=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Python code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('test.env')
print config.get('DB','DB_DATABASE')
```

Output:

> bheng-local

Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: I like the idea of using the parser, but it require me to add more texts on top of my configs file. I don't mind if I am the only one that has it. This config file s is deployed to thousand people already. :( Is there a simple way to grab it base on DB_DATABASE which is the string of file ?

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
file = open('test.env', "r")
read = file.read()

for line in read.splitlines():
    if 'DB_DATABASE=' in line:
        print line.split('=',1)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

from configobj import ConfigObj
conf = ConfigObj('test.env')
print conf['DB_DATABASE']
```

Comment: Using ConfigObj, we do not need to add anything like section header at the start of the .env file to read the variable values from it.

Comment: And without a header, the configuration file can also be read by other languages easily, like Bash for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))
DB_DATABASE = environ.get('DB_DATABASE')
print(DB_DATABASE)
```

This could be another option