# How can i modify information in a .properties file through python

Tags: python

i have a **.properties** file that states`server-ip=` and i made a python program that identifies my **ipv4**, but i want it to go to the proprieties file through the same program and get `server-ip=(my ipv4)`

```
import socket    
socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

I've tired many diferent types of solutions, please a need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If .properties doesn't have sections (usually doesn't) you could check this answer: - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819788/4335378)

Else, you could use configParser:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('filename')

host = config['section-name']['server-ip']
```

Comment: Thank you it helped alot, but where do i put `server-ip` and where do i put `socket.gethostbyname(hostname)`

Comment: I think first you would need to store the ip into a variable e.g. server_ip = config['section-name']['server-ip'], then import the variable into the module that you are using (file.py) and then use socket.gethostbyname(server_ip) moew info here [link](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html) and configparser [link](http://zetcode.com/python/configparser/)