# Python get multiline value from properties file

Tags: python, extract, key-value, multiline, properties-file

I have properties file with multilines and some of the values on more than 1 line. Something like this:

```
first.key=\
        Right,\
        Side,\
        Value
second.key=Second value
third.key=Third value
```

I want to take the value for each key.
I am not able to preprocess the files, so I am not able to surround with triple quotes or anything else.
So if I for examle want to put each key and value in line of the file in a list like:

```
for line in file:
    split = line.split('=')
```

and then get key and value

```
key = split[0]
value = split[1]

print(key) -> first.key
print(value) -> \Right,\Side,\Value


for line in file:
    while line.endswith('\\'):
        line += next(file)

will give me TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

Keep in mind that each line of the properties file is item in a list.
I am able to extract keys and values for each line, but I am struggling how to do it with multiline values. I should probably append next line to previous line if previous line.endswith('\'), but I am not able to figure it out.
EDIT.
['multiline.key=First line of the value\', 'Second line of the value\', 'Third line of the value\', 'Fourth line of the value\', 'Fifth line of the value\', 'another.key=Some value', 'some.key= Another value']
I know how to deal with
'another.key=Some value', 'some.key=Another value'

What I cant figure out is how to extract as single value:

```
First line of the value\\', 'Second line of the value\\', 'Third 
line of the value\\', 'Fourth line of the value\\', 'Fifth line of 
the value\\'
```

for
multiline.key

The file look like this:

```
multiline.key=First line of the value\
Second line of the value\
Third line of the value\
Fourth line of the value\
Fifth line of the value\
another.key=Some value
some.key=Another value
```

Expected result:

```
1st key=multiline.key
1st value=First line of the value\Second line of the value\Third 
line of the value\Fourth line of the value\Fifth line of the value\

2nd key=another.key
2nd value=Some value

3rd key=some.key
3rd value=Another value
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parsing .properties file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819696/parsing-properties-file-in-python)

Comment: What exactly does your intended result look like for the file shown? It's not entirely clear what's an example of what you want, and/or what's an example of what you're (incorrectly) getting.

Comment: I want to get each value in the file even the values on multilines. Which info is missing, so I can improve it?

Comment: After the file you show at the end, show (don't just describe) the output you want from it. I think it's a list of three strings? Or a dictionary whose values are those strings?

Comment: Done. I am splitting the file to lines and adding each line as an item to a list. I know how to split each line before and after '='. My problem is that I don`t know how to handle multiline value, which I have to do before splitting each item to key and value.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like an odd use of a list, but at least it is reasonably clear what you want, if not why. Are you familiar with Python [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? That would be a much more natural choice for representing keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

The properties file is quite identical to an INI file.

You can use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser) with a fake section to easily parse it:

```
data = r"""first.key=\
        Right,\
        Side,\
        Value
second.key=Second value
third.key=Third value"""

import configparser

def read_properties(data: str):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read_string("[dummysection]\n" + data)
    return dict(config['dummysection'])

print(read_properties(data))
```

Output:

```
{'first.key': '\\\nRight,\\\nSide,\\\nValue', 'second.key': 'Second value', 'third.key': 'Third value'}
```

If you wish, you can further process it to remove the `\\\n`:

```
print({k: v.replace("\\\n", "") for k, v in read_properties(data).items()})
```

Output:

```
{'first.key': 'Right,Side,Value', 'second.key': 'Second value', 'third.key': 'Third value'}
```

Comment: This will give me - configparser.ParsingError: Source contains parsing errors: '<string>'

Comment: May you give a properties file that doesn't work?

Comment: I  have added it in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use config parser, I wrote a custom parser

```
import re

with open('delete.txt', "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
    # parsed_data = data.split('=')
    parsed_data = re.split('(?<=[^\\\\])\n', data)
    data_dict = {}
    for element in parsed_data:
        split = element.split('=')
        data_dict[split[0]] = split[1].split('\\\n')
    for key in data_dict:
        print(f"{key} : {data_dict[key]}")
```

The output:

```
first.key : ['', '        Right,', '        Side,', '        Value']
second.key : ['Second value']
third.key : ['Third value']
```

This parser can definitely be improved. But I'd say the hard part has been taken care of

The input file:

```
first.key=\
        Right,\
        Side,\
        Value
second.key=Second value
third.key=Third value
```

Comment: This will give me - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I added the input file

Comment: This approach will add each value as a list of items and make the wnole think very complicated, because I will have to extract and merge the values. In case of multiple line value, it will add each line as a item in the list and it will remove '\\' which is a problem.
The way I see it, I have to find a way to apend next item in a list to the previous item if the previous item endswith('//')

Answer (score -1):

Will this help?

Input file "multiline.txt"

```
first.key=\
        Right,\
        Side,\
        Value
second.key=Second value
third.key=Third value
```

**Code**:

- Created an empty dictionary called `keyvals`.
- If a line contains `=` then get key and value pair by splitting.
- If a line does not contain `=` then append the line to previous value.

```
keyvals = {}
lines= open('multiline.txt', mode='r').read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
    if '=' in line:
        split = line.split('=')
        keyvals[split[0]] = split[1].replace('\\','').strip()
    else:
        keyvals[split[0]] += line.replace('\\','').strip()
print(keyvals)
```

Notes:
splitlines() takes care of newline character `\n`.
strip() removes additional space or tab before or after the text.

Output:

```
{'first.key': 'Right,Side,Value', 'second.key': 'Second value', 'third.key': 'Third value'}
```

Comment: This will give me 
NameError: name 'split' is not defined

Comment: @myname it doesn't.

Comment: @myname Hm... The only way it could throw that error is if the first line of your file is something else, without `=` in it, which is different than what you've shown.

Comment: The code is just the same as shown, except "r", because in context managers the default is reading mode, so "r" is not needed and I have changed the name of the file. The error is for the missing "=" for the else clause. And even if you put "=" there, I will still have KeyError.

Comment: @myname, it works without any errors on the input you initially provided and gives the output you initially wanted. You now changed the input file and required output.

Comment: @myname It runs with *both* files you've shown; there is no error.